# Converting a 3D numpy array to 2D without np.concatenate or np.append

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
x = np.array[[[8, 7, 1, 0, 3],
              [2, 8, 5, 5, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

             [[8, 4, 1, 0, 0],
              [6, 8, 5, 5, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

             [[2, 4, 0, 2, 3],
              [2, 5, 5, 3, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

             [[4, 7, 2, 8, 0],
              [1, 3, 6, 5, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]
```

I have a NumPy array like this and I want to convert it from 3D to 2D as I showed below.

```
x = np.array[[[8, 7, 1, 0, 3, 8, 4, 1, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 2, 8, 0],
              [2, 8, 5, 5, 2, 6, 8, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 6, 5, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Actually my array is really big and I am having problem with working this but works with the same logic.

I can't use np.concatenate or np.append because they are working too slow.

Is there any other way to do this?

Actually I'm using this array for plotting with matplotlib.

```
plt.imshow(x)
plt.show()
```

If there is a way to plot this 3D array with matplotlib without converting it to 2D that would be great.

Comment: Removed `matplotlib` tag since it's not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.hstack()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy-hstack):

```py
print(np.hstack(x))
```

Prints:

```
[[8 7 1 0 3 8 4 1 0 0 2 4 0 2 3 4 7 2 8 0]
 [2 8 5 5 2 6 8 5 5 2 2 5 5 3 2 1 3 6 5 2]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Comment: If speed is an issue, what about using a numba decorator?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney That's a cool option. Sometimes teams don't want an extra dependency just for one task.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [`ndarray.swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.swapaxes.html) + [`ndarray.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html).

```
x.swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(x.shape[1], -1)
array([[8, 7, 1, 0, 3, 8, 4, 1, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 2, 8, 0],
       [2, 8, 5, 5, 2, 6, 8, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 6, 5, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

---

Timeit results:

```
In [102]: %timeit x.swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(x.shape[1], -1)                      
818 ns ± 21.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [103]: %timeit np.hstack(x)                                                  
6.6 µs ± 42.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`swapaxes` + `reshape` here is nearly ~8x faster.

[Online demo in `repl.it`](https://replit.com/@Ch3seR/Super-Tailed-Beast-Rasenshuriken)